# Export .obj with normalized UV coordinates

Tags: uv, export, opengl, coordinates

I want export .obj files from Blender. I export them with normals and UV Coordinates. I then import them into an OpenGl application. In UV Editor i am able to display the coordinates of the cursor normalized. My Problem is that i need to export them normalized cause OpenGL needs them that way. Is there any possibility to do this or do i have to write and application which converts them manually?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The output was normalized but blenders coordinate system starts in the lower right. My coordinate System in OpenGl has (0|0) in the upper left.

Comment: It could be that the image loader that you are using is what's causing the image to appear upside down.  You can look for a code option that switches that.